# mongoose & mongo db multiple inserts or updates using updateMany function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to update/insert many documents in mongodb using mongoose.
So when there is domain that already exist in mongodb I would like to update all other properties like name, desc, etc.

How can I accomplish this using updateMany?

Im using "mongoose": "^5.3.4" version

```
var domains = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'test.com']; 
var companies = [
{ name: 'A', desc: '...', domain: 'google.com'},
{ name: 'B', desc: '...', domain: 'yahoo.com'},
{ name: 'C', desc: '...', domain: 'test.com'},
{ name: 'D', desc: '...', domain: 'xxx.com'}
];
var criteria = {
domain: { $in: domains }
};

CompanyModel.updateMany(criteria, companies, { upsert: true }, function (err, data) {});
```

Comment: Yap! this is one of the solutions that works using bulkWrite, but is it possible to accomplish same functionality using updateMany?
Thanks!

Comment: You need to do looping then.